# Get last X rows using LIMIT and ORDER BY col ASC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

This query is to retrieve some messages, it retuns all of them:

```
$q = "
    SELECT *
    FROM pms
    WHERE
        (
            (id_to = $id and id_from = ".sesion().") 
            OR 
            (id_from = $id and id_to = ".sesion().")
        )
        AND (id > $from)
    ORDER by fecha ASC";
```

The thing is i would like to get the last 50 elements, but I think its ony posible using DESC ordering..

how can i do it?

Do i need to count first how many rows so then can I use `LIMIT $many-$ipp,$many` ? or is there a way to invert the result order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your query a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM pms
    WHERE
        (
            (id_to = $id AND id_from = ".sesion().")
            OR (id_from = $id and id_to = ".sesion().")
        )
        AND id > $from
    ORDER BY fecha DESC
    LIMIT 50
) q1
ORDER BY fecha ASC
```